# I Cannot shutdown or restart the system properly in elementary os 6

Tags: shutdown

[image]Every time when I click shutdown or restart on elementary os 6 , some kind of text shows and the system freeze . It happens every time during the shutdown or restart process. Because of this I cannot properly shutdown the system , I have to long press the power button or to cut the power. I have attached image of the text shown during freeze in shut down process with this. Now I have switched my OS from elementary OS to kubuntu which works perfect. I have already filed issue in Github. I'm using a Dell 5559 laptop.

Comment: Looks like a video driver issue. Would need to examine `/var/log/syslog` for more specific information but, if you've already formatted the machine and replaced Elementary with Kubuntu, the logs will be gone 

Comment: @matigo Thanks for your help , sorry I'm actually a beginner , How can I get logs from /var/log/syslog for the next time if I encounterd this type of problems.

Comment: @matigo Which do you prefer for Linux AMD or Intel for best compatibility ?

Comment: An easy way to access the logs would be via Terminal. Then you can type `sudo vi /var/log/syslog` to view that specific file. As for "best compatibility", that's a separate question. However, both Intel and AMD have some pretty solid support. If you want to have the challenging experience, then most computers from Lenovo or Dell will be the way to go, as they *generally* use hardware that is well known. Fingerprint readers will always be hit-and-miss, though.